# torch.einsum to matmul conversion

Tags: python, torch

I have the following line:

```
torch.einsum("bfts,bhfs->bhts", decay_kernel, decay_q)
```

I have a codebase where I need to convert these einsums to primitive methods like `reshape`, `matmul`, `multiplication`, `sum`, and so on. Is it even possible? I had bunch of other einsums that I could convert them just fine but I can't seem to understand what's going on in this case. Does anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer, you probably solved it in the meantime. I'm working on something similar currently and this way came over this question. Maybe my answer is useful for others coming across this.

I think in general you can convert any `einsum` expression. After all, that is what it also does internally.

To understand what an expression does, it is useful to look for the dimensions that are summed over. Those are the ones that appear in all input expressions, but not in the output. In the present case, this is `f`. If we call the inputs `A` and `B` and the output `C`, this is how the would be defined:

```
C_bhts = \sum_{f} A_bfts B_bhfs
```

With five nested `for`-loops we could compute the result. It would be very inefficient, though. But still helpful to think about it in order to understand what's going on.

Summing over one dimension is what standard matrix multiplication does. However, standard matrix multiplication works with matrices, i.e., 2-dimensional tensors. Here we have a couple more dimensions, but since they should be kept intact, we can solve the entire problem using batch `matmul`, which `torch.matmul` supports out of the box. It expects the "standard matrix" dimensions to come last, though, so we need to rearrange things a bit. Concretely, `bf` and `ft` are those here, so we need to move `s` elsewhere. Then we can do batch `matmul`. For the final result we need to move `s` back to the end. I convinced myself of the correctness using the following code:

```
import torch

b_size = 11
f_size = 13
t_size = 14
s_size = 15
h_size = 16

A_bfts = torch.rand(b_size, f_size, t_size, s_size)
B_bhfs = torch.rand(b_size, h_size, f_size, s_size)
C_bhts = torch.einsum("bfts, bhfs -> bhts", A_bfts, B_bhfs)

# move s axis from back to front
A_sbft = torch.moveaxis(A_bfts, 3, 0)
B_sbhf = torch.moveaxis(B_bhfs, 3, 0)
# perform batch matmul
C_sbht = torch.matmul(B_sbhf, A_sbft)
# move s axis back to last position
C_bhts_2 = torch.moveaxis(C_sbht, 0, -1)

assert torch.allclose(C_bhts, C_bhts_2)
```